# Why are some exhaust cone exposed?

Tags: engine, propulsion

Some engines have an exposed tail/exhaust cone at their exit, protruding aft the nozzle. 
how does that affect the overall thrust and pressure distribution along the walls of the cone?
is it's role similar to an aerospike?

Comment: I think an example could be the A320 CFM 56 vs. IAE V2500 engines. The nacelles on the IAE V2500 are longer, which is based on the design decision to mix the bypass airflow and core engine mass flow inside of the nacelle area which as far as I know can increase the propulsion efficiency but costs extra weight. On the CFM the bypass air is let to the outside right away which saves weight on the nacelles which decreases propulsion efficiency but also decreases the drag of the nacelles and thus can increase the overall efficiency. Just a design choice AFAIK.

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/37959/how-do-exhaust-cones-affect-the-performance-of-turbine-engines?r=SearchResults and https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/37938/4108

Comment: Also https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/20943/4108

Comment: thx but ive seen those threads already. still doesnt answer my question